# Silk version working with

Tags: selenium, junit, silktest

I am working for the first time with silk and te documentation isn't very rich so I am asking you how to know the version of silk that I am working with?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to see the version in the About dialog.

Accessing this dialog might slightly differ depending on the Silk Test client that you are using.

The version should also be mentioned at the top of every help document, for example the Silk Test Release notes.

When you list the programs that are installed on your machine, Silk Test is also displayed along with the version.

Newer versions of Silk Test also include a start page, with the version displayed.